# Cómo saber que dll corresponde a una clase controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

hice una modificacion en mi proyecto **.net mvc**, en un `controller`, y quisiera saber que **DLL** corresponde a esta **clase**, para no tener que compilar y publicar todo el proyecto y solo actualizar la **DLL** del `controller` que modifique.

esto es posible de hacer?

Comment: La dll se llama igual al nombre del proyecto (por lo regular). Si no, click derecho al proyecto donde esta el controlador, luego propiedades y en el tag de aplicacion veras algo que dice: nombre del ensamblado.

Comment: Gracias Orlando ya ví la dll